# Extending a regex to capture multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently have the following regex to capture all content within square brackets:

`regex = /[^[\]]+(?=])/g`

Meaning that:

```
 string = "[Foo: Bar] [Biz: Baz]"
 string.match(regex)
```

In JavaScript will return: ["Foo: Bar", "Biz: Baz"]

for a next step, I want to only get the text that follows a the colon. It is safe to assume that on all matches, we'll consistently have a return where each string in the return array matches the above pattern.

I'm sure there's some way to extend my regex to do this at the same time as finding the text within square brackets, but I'm just not sure how to do so. I've tried using some positive look-aheads, but I have no idea where to add them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `:)` or (`: )` if you need also to match the space after the colon):

```js
var string = "[Foo: Bar] [Biz: Baz]"

var regex = /[^[\]:]+(?=])/g;

console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Comment: `: )` why the literal space? `:\s*)` would be better I think

Comment: I don't think you need to include `space` in inside character class, else it will fail for string such `[Foo: Bar hello] [Biz: Baz]`

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way:

```js
const regex = /\[(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\]/g;
const string = "[Foo: Bar] [Biz: Baz]";
let match;

while(match = regex.exec(string)){
  console.log(`Pro: ${match[1]}`)
  console.log(`Val: ${match[2]}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
\[([^:]+:\s*)([^\]]+)
```

```js
let regex = /\[([^:]+:\s*)([^\]]+)\]/g
let arr = []
let string = "[Foo: Bar] [Biz: Baz]"

while((arr =regex.exec(string))!== null){
  console.log(`key -> ${arr[1]}`)  
  console.log(`val -> ${arr[2]}`)
}
```